# SqlAlchemy-passing models to html code gives me 'str object' has no attribute error

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy

My sqlalchemy db model returns as

`return f"User('{self.user_a}','{self.email}','{self.level}')`

※ When I check Network request headers

`b: User('aaa','kep@keo.com','ccc')`

In my python code

`a.py
selected = request.args.get('b')
  return render_template('abc.html', selected = selected)`

And in my html code

`abc.html 
<input type="text" value={{ selected.user_a.data }}> // I guess here is the problem.`

I want the input value to show up on homepage window.

But here comes and error

`jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError : 'str object' has no attribute 'user'`

Can anyone help me with this error?

Comment: anything in request.args is a string ... no such thing as `"asd".user` what are you expecting to happen?you have not really given us enough to be able to help you other than to say the error message is right ... perhaps you want `selected = session.query(Users).filter(id=request.args.get('b')).first()` ... maybe?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Uploaded more information I got. Sorry thought before editing was enough information. I want to print out input value. But I think I am having problem with calling data on html code..

Comment: @JoranBeasley And nope.. that is not what I am looking for.. I think need to change code on html or add some function a.py. But do not no what is wrong.

Comment: you are passing a string(`"User('aaa','kep@keo.com','ccc')"`) ... you **cannot** pass anything but a string in any request args (or even request.form) .... ... you need to pass an ID then retrieve the user from that id ...

Answer (score 1):

This exception means that you are trying to access an attribute from a string rather than an object. You are expecting `selected` as an object but actually, it is a string. You need to convert it into the JSON before passing it into the template.

```
import json
selected = request.args.get('b')
selected_object = json.loads(selected)
return render_template('abc.html', selected = selected_object)
```